# Pass values to child in LayoutBuilder

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layoutbuilder

I'm using LayoutBuilder and would like to pass values to a child widget:

```
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(constraints.maxWidth / 10),
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Invalid constant value
```

Is there a way to pass constraints.maxWidth to the child widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the const keyword before EdgeInsets.all because constraints.maxWidth is not a constant term